# What does this single line in Python do on a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a grayscale image and I was trying to use OpenCV in Python to process it so it would be more suitable for my application. I ended up writing the following line:

```
img += ((img - 127)/(255 - 127))*(255 - img)
```

The output worked well for my application but I'm not sure what exactly it is doing. I broke down my originally intended algorithm into the code below and the output is different from that of the code above.

```
for p in range(img.shape[0]):
    for q in range(img.shape[1]):
        a = float(img[p][q] - 127)
        b = float(255 - 127)
        c = float(255 - img[p][q])
        new = img[p][q] + int(round((a/b)*c))
        if new < 0:
            new = 0
        if new > 255:
            new = 255
        img[p][q] = 255 - new
```

Can someone please explain to me the step by step process of what is happening in the single line of code that I first wrote? Thank you!

Comment: You wrote a line of code and you don't know what is doing? How did you wrote it then?

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with OpenCV---your image is simply a `np.array()`. I've removed the OpenCV tag and text from the title and instead replaced with `numpy` to more accurately reflect the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just break your one-liner down statement by statement. It's a little confusing/non-intuitive, and there are better, clearer ways to get the same result. Let's start with a random image:

```
>>> img = np.uint8(np.random.rand(100, 100)*255)
>>> img
array([[216, 182, 101, ...,  22,  78, 253],
       [ 50,  52,  40, ..., 136,  15,  59],
       [ 35, 203, 124, ..., 143, 120, 175],
       ...,
       [133,  36,  77, ...,  71,  70, 235],
       [ 43,  52, 116, ...,  62,  66,   7],
       [139, 152, 210, ..., 134,  15,  19]], dtype=uint8)
```

Now what does the first operation do?

```
>>> img-127
array([[ 89,  55, 230, ..., 151, 207, 126],
       [179, 181, 169, ...,   9, 144, 188],
       [164,  76, 253, ...,  16, 249,  48],
       ...,
       [  6, 165, 206, ..., 200, 199, 108],
       [172, 181, 245, ..., 191, 195, 136],
       [ 12,  25,  83, ...,   7, 144, 148]], dtype=uint8)
```

Note that there is a lot of overflow here. If you have a `uint8` element that is less than 127, then numbers that become negative when subtracted off wrap around and get subtracted off 256. So for e.g. in the first row, third column:

```
101-127 = -26 = 256-26 = 230
```

Then the next operation binarizes this result:

```
>>> (img-127)/128
array([[0, 0, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, ..., 0, 1, 0],
       ...,
       [0, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 1, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Taking a `uint8` image and dividing by two is the most basic way to threshold or binarize an image. Note here that everything between 0 and 127 in the subtracted image is set to 0, and everything between 128 and 255 is set to 1. Now, normally a binary image is used as a labelling scheme to tell you something (e.g. foreground, background) and then used as a mask in this context. So what are these elements telling you? What does 0 correspond to? What does 1 correspond to? Taking overflow into account, any number that was greater than 128 in the image was subtracted to be below 128. And any number lower than 127 was subtracted off, overflowed, and is now higher than 127. Then the result is binarized. Note that this is identical to simply binarizing *first*, and then flipping the result *except* this one-liner uses 127 and not 128 for the threshold, so this isn't exactly true:

```
>>> ((img-127)/128 == 1-(img/128)).all()
False
>>> ((img-128)/128 == 1-(img/128)).all()
True
```

Anyways, this binarization is applied to the opposite of the image:

```
>>> ((img-127)/128) * (255-img)
array([[  0,   0, 154, ..., 233, 177,   0],
       [205, 203, 215, ...,   0, 240, 196],
       [220,   0, 131, ...,   0, 135,   0],
       ...,
       [  0, 219, 178, ..., 184, 185,   0],
       [212, 203, 139, ..., 193, 189, 248],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 240, 236]], dtype=uint8)
```

So what do we have at the end here? What are these elements?

Well, the binarization selected the low numbers in the original image as ones. And then this binary image grabs those low elements from the opposite of the image. So all the elements here will be strictly greater than 127, and each positive element corresponds to the opposite of the image where the brightness was low in the original image. Finally, this result is added to the original image.

```
>>> img
array([[216, 182, 101, ...,  22,  78, 253],
       [ 50,  52,  40, ..., 136,  15,  59],
       [ 35, 203, 124, ..., 143, 120, 175],
       ...,
       [133,  36,  77, ...,  71,  70, 235],
       [ 43,  52, 116, ...,  62,  66,   7],
       [139, 152, 210, ..., 134,  15,  19]], dtype=uint8)
>>> ((img-127)/128) * (255-img)
array([[  0,   0, 154, ..., 233, 177,   0],
       [205, 203, 215, ...,   0, 240, 196],
       [220,   0, 131, ...,   0, 135,   0],
       ...,
       [  0, 219, 178, ..., 184, 185,   0],
       [212, 203, 139, ..., 193, 189, 248],
       [  0,   0,   0, ...,   0, 240, 236]], dtype=uint8)
>>> img + ((img-127)/128) * (255-img)
array([[216, 182, 255, ..., 255, 255, 253],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 136, 255, 255],
       [255, 203, 255, ..., 143, 255, 175],
       ...,
       [133, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 235],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [139, 152, 210, ..., 134, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
```

Note what's going on here. The original image at row 2, column 1 for example has a value of 50. This element of 50 is less than 127, so it's selected by the binarization. Then it grabs the opposite of this value, which is 255-50. Thus if we add this opposite value to the image, it will send the value back to 50+(255-50) = 255. This happens for *every single value* in the image that is less than 127. In other words, every darker pixel (less than 127) is set to white. That's all it's doing.

This is, IMO, a *completely ridiculous way to do this operation*. This entire beast is simply equivalent to:

```
>>> new_img = img.copy()
>>> new_img[new_img<127] = 255
>>> new_img
array([[216, 182, 255, ..., 255, 255, 253],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 136, 255, 255],
       [255, 203, 255, ..., 143, 255, 175],
       ...,
       [133, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 235],
       [255, 255, 255, ..., 255, 255, 255],
       [139, 152, 210, ..., 134, 255, 255]], dtype=uint8)
>>> final = img + ((img-127)/128) * (255-img)
>>> (final == new_img).all()
True
```

So I think this probably explains it well enough to ignore the double `for` loop aspect of your question.